# Could not find generator mini_test:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

I expected these generators to be available:

```
$ rails g
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

MiniTest:
  mini_test:controller
  mini_test:helper
  mini_test:install
  mini_test:mailer
  mini_test:model
  mini_test:scaffold
```

So I ran:

```
$ rails g mini_test:install
```

But got this error:

```
Could not find generator mini_test:install.
```

As for my environment, here is the relevant portion of my `Gemfile`:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'minitest-rails'
end
```

And the resulting portions of my `Gemfile.lock`:

```
minitest (2.12.1)
minitest-rails (0.0.7)
  minitest (~> 2.12)
  rails (~> 3.1)
```

I am now in the process of debugging this. I would appreciate any tips. In any case, I will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [minitest-rails issue #41 - Generators are not found](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/issues/41):

> Try the prerelease gem, 0.1.0.alpha. Its a different approach and you'll need to update any existing tests.

I just confirmed that this worked for me:

```
$ rails g mini_test:install
create  test
create  test/minitest_helper.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in the 0.1 release of minitest-rails.

https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails